# C : Static to dynamic allocation on multiple dimension array

Tags: c, malloc, typedef

I'm currently stuck with a legacy code using multiple dimensions arrays :

```
#define B 25
int Table[A][B][C][D][E][F];
```

I need to change the B constant by a dynamic value. The thing is, I need to keep the table the same way it used to be so that I won't have anything else but the allocation du rewrite.

I'd like to have your ideas / comments on how to do such a thing.

Currently I'm trying to typedef the end of the table ([C][D][E]) to malloc it at allocation time, but I'm stuck with errors about the Table not being as legacy code wants it ...

```
//int32_t Table[A][B][C][D][E][F];
int32_t* Table[A];

typedef int32_t type_1_t[E][F];
typedef type_1_t type_2_t[C][D];

for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
  Table[i] = (int32_t*) malloc (sizeof (type_2_t) * dynamic_B);
```

Using this, I get an error ("error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector") when using the table.

```
XXX = Table [a][b][c][d][e][f];
```

Comment: What does the legacy code want? What are the errors?

Comment: Using the Table with every dimensions. Currently the errors I get are "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector" which may come from my typedefs or mallocs that's why I didn't post the code I'm trying right now.

Comment: If legacy code sees this table as a multidimensionnal array, I don't see how it could handle your kind of solution with non contiguous memory regions, as it will try to access to your table with simple dereference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the wrong type:

```
int32_t* Table[A];
```

should be in fact

```
int32_t (*Table[A])[C][D][E][F];
```

or, as you typedef'd it

```
type_2_t *Table[A];
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: This doesn't seems to solve the problem, I still get the same errors when using Table[a][b][c][d][e][f].

Comment: The typedef'd version doesn't work, the first one does compile but segfault (in my code).

Comment: The code on ideone test the [0][0][0][0][0] adress which is often good (means does work) no matter what you do ...

Comment: For the segfaults, check that you don't cross the range of the indexes.

Comment: Ok nevermind for the typedef'd version, it does work indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

Eyes hurt!
Why not declare it as int * * * * * *Table and malloc it in 5 nested for loops? This way you're future proofed if any other dimensions decide to go dynamic :)

```
Table = malloc(A * sizeof(int *****));
for (i=0; i<A; ++i)
{
  Table[i] = malloc(B * sizeof(int ****));
  for (i1=0; i1<B; ++i1)
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: i most likely got the number of indirections wrong.

Comment: I don't want to use this solution because I'm lazy (writting loops) and there's obvious performance issues.

Comment: Are you allocating this array inside of some inner loop then? If it's done once, the performance difference shouldn't be too annoying. And IMO if you're lazy today it will bite you in 2 months :)

Comment: I'm talking about performance issues later in the program when accessing the table.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define  SIZE_B (C*D*E*F*sizeof(int32_t))
int32_t***** Table[A];


or (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
  Table[i] = (int32_t*****) malloc ( SIZE_B * dynamic_B);
```

Edited 2: The code above does absolutely nothing and is complete rubbish. Leaving it as a reminder to check code thoroughly before I post

Edited 3: This works like a charm here, finally :)

```
#define SIZE_B (C*D*E*F*sizeof(int))

typedef int t2[C][D][E][F];


    t2* ar[A];

    int dynB = 3;

    for(int i=0;i<A;i++)
    {
        ar[i] = (t2*)malloc(SIZE_B * dynB);
    }
```

Comment: I won't be able to acces the table using multiple dimensions with this! I want the legacy code (which uses Table [a][b][c][d][e][f]) to work...

Comment: This is nonsense. You cast a pointer-to-array to a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer which really won't do the right thing.

Comment: @jpalecek Yes you are right, it compiled and printed, so I thought it worked, but know when I checked it printed 0xcdcdcdcd. Can't blame a guy for trying to cheat the compiler :)

Comment: You would need to allocate every single dimension, not just one of them.